# Correct Behavior+Syntax for C++ `constexpr` `template` Lambda Function Parameters

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider the following simple example in C++:

```cpp
template< class Titer > [[nodiscard]] constexpr
auto calc_sum(
    Titer cstart, Titer cend,
    std::function< decltype(*cstart) (Titer) > val_from_iter_fn =
        [](Titer iter) -> decltype(*cstart) { return *iter; }
) noexcept {
    std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(*cstart)> val{};
    while (cstart!=cend) val+=val_from_iter_fn(cstart++);
    return val;
}

[[nodiscard]] constexpr float calc_sum_f( float const* data, size_t len ) noexcept {
    return calc_sum( data,data+len );
}
```

The idea is that `calc_sum(⋯)` can be fed a range and optionally a function to extract the required data from the iterator (useful e.g. if the iterator returns an object and you're only interested in one field of the object).  If no such function is provided, it uses a default implementation which just tries to dereference it.

---

I asked three different compilers and got three different answers, which means at least two of them are wrong.  What is the right answer?  (I don't think the particular language version matters for this question, and so am not tagging it specifically, but it's C++23.)

---

### GCC

(Compiles with no complaint.)

---

### Clang

Clang fails to compile, claiming the function is not `constexpr`:

```
<source>:12:31: error: constexpr function never produces a constant expression [-Winvalid-constexpr]
   12 | [[nodiscard]] constexpr float calc_sum_f( float const* data, size_t len ) noexcept {
      |                               ^
<source>:13:9: note: non-literal type 'std::function<decltype(*cstart) (const float *)>' (aka 'function<const float &(const float *)>') cannot be used in a constant expression
   13 |         return calc_sum( data,data+len );
      |                ^
```

I don't understand what Clang is on about here.  It doesn't have to be a literal type; it's an actual parameter, and anyway it's a compile-time constant.  If I remove `constexpr` from the declaration of `calc_sum_f(⋯)`, it compiles with no complaint.

---

### MSVC

MSVC claims it can't find `cstart`:

```
<source>(5): error C2065: 'cstart': undeclared identifier
[...]
```

I can make it compile by changing `decltype(*cstart)` to `decltype(*Titer{})` (I only have to change the second occurrence, in the lambda, where the error occurs).  I feel like this shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: `std::function` doesn't work at compile-time. And the whole `calc_sum()` isn't `constexpr` in the first place. *"at least two of them are wrong"* Not necessarily. Slapping `constexpr` on a function that can never work at compile-time was [ill-formed, no diagnostic required](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2448r2.html) pre-C++23 (now well-defined), so GCC failing to produce the error is still conforming.

Comment: Just drop `std::function` and do `typename F`, `F &&val_from_iter_fn`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Regarding the workaround, I actually initially tried essentially that, but got an error (in all three compilers) in `calc_sum_f(⋯)` that the type couldn't be deduced (though I frankly don't understand why it can't be).

Comment: Can you show that version of your code?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/WsveMzhf4

Comment: Template arguments are never deduced from default function arguments. One solution is to remove the default argument altogether, and add a second overload without the extra parameter, that calls the first one.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat "Template arguments are never deduced from default function arguments." Mmm right. One thing I tried about that was to specify a default *type* for the argument, and that sortof works but it's not clear what to put in there (e.g. `std::function<⋯>` is problematic, as above).¶ The code I'm working on actually currently uses multiple overloads, but I'm trying to rewrite it to avoid a combinatorial explosion (there are many more parameters that are optional than just the function).

Comment: If you make the lambda a global variable, you can pass a `decltype(lambda)`. Another trick is to do `typename F = std::nullptr`, `F &&func = nullptr`, then use `if constexpr (std::is_null_pointer_v<F>)` to set the default behavior.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Good suggestions. I think I'll end up using something like that. Thanks for resolving my XY Problem.